AWX-Operator Exposing on HTTPS
I am very new to AWX. I have an instance installed and working per the documentation found here https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_Stream_9&p=ansible&f=9 but am having difficulty understanding how to expose the ansible-awx-service on an HTTPS port.
I understand that Minikube has its own IP addressing space but Ideally what I want to happen is have the IP/DNS for the host Centos machine load the AWX service on HTTPS
Please let me know what I can do
I believe I have nginx working per another guide but the service still requires a port forward to get the AWX interface to load.
